# Splitting Columns Values into other columns based on character position

Tags: python, dataframe

I'd like to split a column of a data frame into two other columns based on the position of the character. For example, if there was a delimiter between the two values I'd use `str.split()`. However, I do not and only know the first 12 characters should be assigned to a column and the remaining 7 should be assigned to another column. If this was one instance I'd use `column1 = composite_symbol[:13] and column2 = composite_symbol[13:]`.

composite_symbol

 AT0000730007B1WVF68

 AT00009375034943402

to

column1
row 1 AT0000730007

 row 2 AT0000937503

column2

 row 1 B1WVF68

 row 2 4943402

composite_symbol

 AT0000730007B1WVF68

 AT00009375034943402

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming df is your dataframe and 'composite_symbol' is the column made of strings

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'composite_symbol': ['AT0000730007B1WVF68','AT00009375034943402']})
```

The first column will have the first 12 characters

```
df['column1'] = df.composite_symbol.str[:12]
```

The last one will have the following ones

```
df['column2'] = df.composite_symbol.str[12:]
```

Is that what you need ?